# Running a method using multithread in java

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, httpresponse, runnable

I have method as

```
public List<SenderResponse> sendAllFiles(String folderName) {
    List<File> allFiles = getListOfFiles();
    List<SenderResponse> finalResponse = new ArrayList<SenderResponse>();
    for (File file : allFiles) {
        finalResponse.getResults().add(sendSingleFile(file));
    }
    return finalResponse;
}
```

which is running as a single thread. I want run `sendSingleFile(file)` using `multithread` so I can reduce the total time taken to send files.

how can I run `sendSingleFile(file)` using `multithread`s for various files and get the final response?

I found few articles using `threadpoolexecutor`. But how to handle the response got during the `sendSingleFile(file)` and add it to one Final `SenderResponse`?

I am kind of new to multi-thread. Please suggest the best way to process these files.

Comment: You could use a parallel stream  `finalResponse = allFiles.stream().parallel().map(this::sendSinfleFile).collect();`. I am not sure what `getResults()` does.

Comment: @eckes I think that call to getResults() is just one indication that the code given by the OP doesnt work at all.

Comment: Your sequential code doesn't even compile. Fix that first. Then read the tutorial about executors (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html), and the relevant javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection). Then try something.

Answer (score 1):

Define an executor service

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREAD); //Define integer value of MAX_THREAD
```

Then for each job you can do something like this:-

```
Callable<SenderResponse> task = () -> {
    try {
        return sendSingleFile(file);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Interrupted", e);
    }
};

Future<SenderResponse> future = executor.submit(task);

future.get(MAX_TIME_TO_WAIT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  //Blocking call. MAX_TIME_TO_WAIT is max time future will wait for the process to execute.
```

Comment: Is missing the "collect" part where all the different responses get bundled into a single list.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But I intended this code for one job only. So, OP have to put it in a loop for submitting jobs and then he can do a loop on list of future to get responses..

Comment: For example, yep. Whatever. Your answer is probably as good as mine; just more specific; so have my vote.

Answer (score 0):

You **start** by writing code that works works for the single-thread solution. The code you posted wouldn't even compile; as the method signature says to return `SenderResponse`; whereas you use/return a `List<SenderResponse>` within the method!

When that stuff works, you continue with this:

- You create an instance of 
  [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), based on as many threads as you want to
- You submit **tasks** into that service.
- Each tasks *knows* about that result list object. The task does its work, and adds the result to that result list.

The one point to be careful about: making sure that `add()` is synchronized somehow - having multiple threads update an ordinary ArrayList is not safe.

Comment: I once started by writing code that works for the single-thread solution (a week ago actually) and then I had to completely rewrite it for multithreading.

Comment: It's not a question. Just a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. The point is: the OP doesn't even have correct code for the single threaded solution. Beyond that; this is about experience: when you know what you are doing, you can put down a single-threaded solution that doesnt give to much trouble when enhancing it for multi-threading.

Answer (score 0):

For your situation, I would use a work stealing pool (ForkJoin executor service) and submit "jobs" to it. If you're using guava, you can wrap that in a `listeningDecorator` which will allow you to add a listener on the futures it returns.

Example:

```
// create the executor service
ListeningExecutorService exec = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newWorkStealingPool());

for(Foo foo : bar) {
    // submit can accept Runnable or Callable<T>
    final ListenableFuture<T> future = exec.submit(() -> doSomethingWith(foo));
    // Run something when it is complete.
    future.addListener(() -> doSomeStuff(future), exec);
}
```

Note that the listener will be called whether the future was successful or not.